# Set colors for terminator to terminal's

Tags: command-line, colors, terminator

I'm using Ubuntu 16.04, I installed Terminator and noticed it has different colors than the standard terminal. The contrast is not high enough and I like the standard terminal colors.

So my question is how can I set terminator's colors to the standard terminal's colors?

If you know it, please answer simple and straightforward because my Ubuntu knowledge is very limited! :P Best would be some generic copy pastable commands.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In `terminator`, the color palette can be edited in the preferences (Right Click → Preferences) under Profiles → Colors:

[image: right click menu]

[image: preferences window]

There are several schemes you can choose from as well as a “Custom” scheme that let’s you edit the palette directly – the “Linux” scheme may be what you want. These settings are stored in `~/.config/terminator/config`, but I advise against editing this file from the command line, too easy to snafu.

Answer (score 2):

Editing the config file is not difficult.

I had to as the 'preferences' option does not show up when I right click. maybe because I set up right click to paste, similar to putty behavior.

[image]

Anyway I changed the config from:

```
palette = "#000000:#cd0000:#00cd00:#cdcd00:#0000ee:#cd00cd:#00cdcd:#e5e5e5:#7f7f7f:#ff0000:#00ff00:#ffff00:#5c5cff:#ff00ff:#00ffff:#ffffff"
```

to:

```
palette = "#073642:#d30102:#859900:#b58900:#268bd2:#d33682:#2aa198:#eee8d5:#002b36:#cb4b16:#586e75:#657b83:#839496:#6c71c4:#93a1a1:#fdf6e3"
```

Which is much better.

Answer (score 1):

Try to look here: [Terminator does not looks like the same as Gnome terminal even used system-theme color](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1140521/terminator-does-not-looks-like-the-same-as-gnome-terminal-even-used-system-theme)

They change to ubuntu colors on ~/.config/terminator/config

```
[global_config]
[keybindings]
[layouts]
  [[default]]
    [[[child1]]]
      parent = window0
      type = Terminal
    [[[window0]]]
      parent = ""
      type = Window
[plugins]
[profiles]
  [[default]]
    background_color = "#2c001e"
    cursor_color = "#aaaaaa"
    foreground_color = "#f3f3f3"
```